# QML Binding with Javascript array access to QObject Property

Tags: qt, qml

My `rootModel` has property called `checklist`. `checklist` is QObject that has `bool` properties that needs to be controlled by a `Checkbox {}`. I'm trying to reduce copy and paste code. Below is my custom checkbox `MyCheckbox.qml`

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0
import QtQuick 2.0    

Checkbox {
    id: myCheckbox
    property string property: ""


    Binding {
        target: myCheckbox
        property: "checked"
        value: rootModel.checklist[property]
    }

    checked: rootModel.checklist[property]
    onCheckedChanged: rootModel.checklist[property] = checked
}
```

Example of usage of `MyCheckbox.qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {

   Row {  
      MyCheckbox {
           property: "check1" //Access to rootModel.checklist.check1
      }

      MyCheckbox {
           property: "check2" //Access to rootModel.checklist.check2
      }
   }
}
```

It get the following error for the `Binding{}`:

```
QQmlExpression: Expression file:///myChecklistCheckbox.qml:14:16 depends on non-NOTIFYable properties:
      QQmlBind::property
```

How do I fix this error and get the QmlEngine to bind the property properly. `checklist` has signals for each property and `NOTIFY` works correctly if do something like this:

```
    Binding {
        target: myCheckbox
        property: "checked"
        value: rootModel.checklist.check1
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented in [this page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-propertybinding.html#creating-property-bindings-from-javascript) you can do something like this:

```
CheckBox {
    id: myCheckbox
    property string property: ""

    checked:  rootModel.checklist[property]
    onCheckedChanged: {rootModel.checklist[property] = checked; rebind();}

    function rebind() {
        checked = Qt.binding(function(){ return rootModel.checklist[property]})
    }
}
```